# Using Zurb Foundation 6 javascript in a Django project

Tags: django, zurb-foundation

I have an existing Django project that I would like to use Zurb Foundation in (version 6.4.2 to be exact). I figured from the documentation that you can just reference the CDN or download the relevant files to your static folder and reference them from there. I have done the latter via

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'foundation/css/foundation.min.css' %}" type='text/css' />

<script src="{% static 'foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'foundation/js/vendor/what-input.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'foundation/js/vendor/foundation.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

The css seems to be working as expected, however the javascript does not seem to work at all. When I paste a snippet from say [enter link description here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/toggler.html) , say

```
<p><a data-toggle="menuBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menuBar">Expand!</a></p>
<ul class="menu" id="menuBar" data-toggler=".expanded">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

nothing happens. The menu loads but the menu does not expand as it does in the linked documentation page. Am I not referencing the correct files or do I need to install or load anything I haven' t mentioned? Or is this a Django problem and if so is there a work around?

Comment: So the problem was fixed once I moved the references all the way to the bottom of the body tag, because that is what the included index.html page looked like. This seems to have fixed the problem and everything works as expected now. What is this all about? Why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was simple JQuery. I think it is just best practice to have it at the bottom but since you have used `$(document).foundation();` the page has to be loaded to initialize the foundations plugins used on the page. Essentially, you cannot make x red if x doesn't exist on the page/DOM.

**Initialize Foundation**

After you have included the Foundation JavaScript, just add a simple call to initialize all plugins on your page.

We recommend that you initialize Foundation at the end of the page.

HTML

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

taken from https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html but that's out of date since the current release is 6.6.2